# How to print table from packet in R?

Tags: r

In package MASS there is data Insurance packet.
And I need to:
Print table, which row will be Group and column will be  Age, in the table should be the sum of Claims meaning.

Can someone help me to do this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about performing simple operations in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use the `xtabs` function, as in

```
library("MASS")
data(Insurance)
xtabs(Claims ~ Group + Age, data = Insurance)

R> xtabs(Claims ~ Group + Age, data = Insurance)
        Age
Group    <25 25-29 30-35 >35
  <1l     67    70    56 346
  1-1.5l 105   169   197 979
  1.5-2l  46   124   153 540
  >2l     11    41    47 200
```

You can treat that as any other matrix and subset it etc.